# Django Heroku thread timeouts

Tags: django, heroku, timeout, gunicorn

I am running Django on Heroku with gunicorn.  Several times a day I receive desc="Connection closed without response" in my logs.  These requests are always to static content that is part of the slug uploaded to the server.  Immediately after this error the gunicorn worker threads go critical, timeout and restart themselves.

I have no clue as to what is causing this since I have uninstalled new relic and the files being served are all local to the slug on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be to do with your "backlog" and max_requests settings...
If you have a backlog > 1  then when your gunicorn thread restarts after max_requests is hit, I think all the requests in the backlog are dropped....

I've been seeing this on my heroku when running blitz.io tests...  I reduced backlog to 1 and now I only see one Connection closed without response error per web dyno...

I don't know why this seems to occur, I thought the backlog would be held in the parent process and passed onto the respawned child when it was up...